# "Redirect" user after right credentials with PyQt5

Tags: python, django, pyqt5

I made a Django API that returns if the user was logged successfully. I use that API result to log in the user in PyQt. My code is as follows:

```
import json
import sys

import requests
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

from PyQtProject.request_login import querystring, headers


class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Login na aplicação'
        self.left = 600
        self.top = 400
        self.width = 380
        self.height = 200
        self.username = None
        self.password = None
        self.button = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        # Create an username textbox
        self.username = QLineEdit(self)
        self.username.move(20, 20)
        self.username.resize(280, 40)
        self.username.setPlaceholderText('Usuário')

        # Create a password textbox
        self.password = QLineEdit(self)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.password.move(20, 80)
        self.password.resize(280, 40)
        self.password.setPlaceholderText('Senha')

        # Create a button in the window
        self.button = QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.button.move(20, 140)

        # connect button to function on_click
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        username = self.username.text()
        password = self.password.text()

        querystring.update({'username': username, 'password': password})

        url = "http://localhost:8000/login_api/"

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

        result = json.loads(response.content)[0]['message']
        if result:
            pass
        else:
            QMessageBox.question(
                self, 'Erro', "Usuário não autenticado!", QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok
            )
            self.username.setText("")
            self.password.setText("")

    def upload_file_page(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I need to "redirect" the user to an upload file "page" in PyQt.

My initial thought was to clear the entire screen and replace the previous items by the new ones.

How can I accomplish that?

** By "redirect" I mean that I want to close the previous window and open another one.

Comment: explain yourself better, what does redirect mean in this context? On a website it means changing your view without the user changing the URL, but in a GUI there is no such concept except what you have in your mind

Comment: I think that would be to close the previous window and open another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it is better to have a class that handles the logic of the "pages" similar to the Django controller, so having your particular logic to be able to show or hide the pages.

On the other hand in your case the requests are to a local url but considering that it can also be a remote url so that can take a long time so it would block the GUI, to avoid this I have implemented a worker who will live in another thread avoiding freezing .

```py
import sys
from functools import partial
import json

import requests

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QLineEdit,
    QMessageBox,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QObject, Qt, QThread, QTimer

from PyQtProject.request_login import querystring, headers


class LoginPage(QWidget):
    send_credentials = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Login na aplicação"
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        # Create an username textbox
        self.username = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Usuário")
        self.password = QLineEdit(echoMode=QLineEdit.Password, placeholderText="Senha")
        self.button = QPushButton("Login")

        self.username.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.password.setFixedHeight(40)
        self.setFixedSize(380, 200)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.username)
        lay.addWidget(self.password)
        lay.addWidget(self.button, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft)

        # connect button to function on_click
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        username = self.username.text()
        password = self.password.text()

        self.send_credentials.emit(username, password)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def failed(self):
        QMessageBox.question(
            self, "Erro", "Usuário não autenticado!", QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok
        )
        self.username.clear()
        self.password.clear()


class UploadFilePage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(QLabel("UploadFilePage"))


class RequestsWorker(QObject):
    logged = pyqtSignal(bool)

    @pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def login_request(self, username, password):
        querystring.update({"username": username, "password": password})
        url = "http://localhost:8000/login_api/"
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
        result = json.loads(response.content)[0]["message"]
        self.logged.emit(bool(result))


class Controller(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        thread = QThread(self)
        thread.start()

        self._requests_worker = RequestsWorker()
        self._requests_worker.logged.connect(self.onLogged)

        self._login_page = LoginPage()
        self._login_page.send_credentials.connect(self._requests_worker.login_request)
        self._login_page.show()

        self._upload_page = UploadFilePage()

    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def onLogged(self, result):
        if result:
            self._login_page.close()
            self._upload_page.show()
        else:
            self._login_page.failed()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    controller = Controller()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```